# Heroku + Refinery + S3 : get "Unknown region" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, amazon-s3, heroku, refinerycms

Following

> [How to Install Refinery on Heroku](http://refinerycms.com/guides/how-to-install-refinery-on-heroku)

I get `ArgumentError (Unknown region: "EU_Ireland")`

UPDATE:
I'm actually using fog (not aws-s3) as required in last version:

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/heroku/ennefoto$ egrep "fog|aws" Gemfile
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'fog'
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/heroku/ennefoto$ egrep "fog|aws" Gemfile.lock
    fog (0.8.2)
  fog
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/heroku/ennefoto$
```

... anyway using a standard BUCKET (US) it works. That seems the same problem happened with 'aws/s3' ...

Any idea ?

Does anybody know what's the region syntax is like ? I tryed EU_Ireland, Ireland, eu-ireland ... but that's the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use syntax like this for the region using Fog: `us-east-1`... For Ireland, it is `eu-west-1`

By the way, here is a full listing:  http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3912#s3

Comment: Just to track & remember that: eu-west-1 it works, while EU doesn't works.

Comment: Glad to hear it Luca!  Thanks for updating